# Does a current source override the v=ir rule?

Tags: voltage, current

Consider:

[image]

Here I have two almost identical circuits. The only difference is that the first one has a current source with the voltage source. Shouldn't the current in the upper circuit be v/r, or 10 V/1000 Ω = 0.01 A? Why is it 5 A here?

Comment: The point between R7 and the current source is not ground. Therefore the voltage accross R7 is not 10V. See answers bellow for what it is.

Comment: ...In order to apply the v=ir rule (a.k.a., Ohm's Law), you have to measure the right V and the right I.  The I is the current through a resistor, the V is the voltage _dropped_ by the same resistor (i.e., the voltage difference between its two end points), and the R is the resistance of the same resistor.

Answer (score 15):

You can think of a current source as a smart voltage source. It creates a voltage across itself so that the desired current is reached in the attached circuit.

So, looking at your circuit...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQZ0yb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ask yourself, what voltage would need to be at point **B** in order to have 5A passing thorough **R1**

Well, from OHM's law, the voltage drop across **R1** must be **5,000V**, so point B must be at **10V - 5,000  = -4,990V**.

So the current source is generating a large negative voltage at its top.

Another way you can look at it is, for 5A to flow through this circuit, the circuit equivalent resistance must be \$2\Omega\$. The current source then must have an effective resistance of \$-998\Omega\$. Yes that is correct, the current source has a negative resistance in this instance.

Comment: We're going to need a bigger heatsink.

Answer (score 10):

No, the voltage across the resistor is \$V_R = I\cdot R = 5 \textrm{A} \cdot1\textrm{k} \Omega = 5000\:\textrm{V}\$

Hence, the voltage across the current source is \$10\textrm{V} - 5000\textrm{V} = -4990\textrm{V}\$

Why is that? 
Well because you have a current source in your circuit.

A current source is a circuit element that maintains a prescribed (set) current (5A) regardless of the voltage across its terminals.

Comment: And adding a real-world caveat to this - a real voltage source maintains a constant voltage *up to some maximum current*, and a real current source maintains a constant current *up to some maximum voltage*.  In your simulator, your current source will have no problems delivering -4990V.  In real life, you may find it behaves a bit differently!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing can "override" a law, this is what is making it a law. In the upper circuit we know the current forced by current source to be `5A`. It makes the voltage drop on the resistor to be `Vr = 5A * 1K = 5000V`. But we also know that the total voltage on the branch is 10V as forced by the ideal voltage source on the left. It makes the voltage drop on the current source to be `10V-5000V = -4990V`. Because the ideal current source does not mandate any specific voltage drop on it, this negative drop is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Well, reality can override it.  After all, the "law" is for ideal resistors, of which I have none in my parts kit ;-)

Comment: @CortAmmon Well, every law comes packed with conditions it applies to. Ohms Law is not restricting ideal current sources.

Comment: @CortAmmon: I'd say that Ohm's Law *defines* resistance.  The fact that a device called a "100 ohm" resistor may have a resistance which isn't constantly 100.0000 ohms doesn't mean that it disobeys Ohm's Law; it simply means that its resistance isn't a constant 100.0000 ohms.

Comment: @CortAmmon actually OHM law really states "The resistance of an object is the amount of voltage you will measure across it if you feed one amp through it." That applies to all things. it may vary with the rate of change of the applied current and may not be linear, but at any time point and given value it always applies.

Comment: @CortAmmon That means the R value is a measured value from OHM's law. The resistors in you box are marked in OHM'S law resistance.. ideal or not. They have a tolerance because the manufacturer / standard  defines a "close enough" percentage range for each family.

Comment: @Trevor Can you cite your source for that particular version of Ohm's Law?  I'm pretty darn sure that isn't what it actually states.  If so, the resistors in my box are *really* not ohmic resistors.  Most of the resistors I have (especially above 10k ohm) have an incandescent failure mode if you try to cram 1 amp through them.

Comment: The point of my comment is to *never* believe something can't happen because the 1st order model predicts that it can't happen.  Reality always trumps laws, because most "laws" are actually not laws but approximations that are useful.

Comment: @CortAmmon I do agree LAW is not exactly a great word for it. But resistance is mathematically derived from volts and current, and you can't break the math. re reference... http://www.science20.com/chatter_box/genius_georg_ohm-86122

Comment: @CortAmmon the issue comes into making the assumption that components are linear. Nothing is linear. As you say, at 1A a 10K resistor will suddenly have a much higher resistance that wont return to 10K when the current is removed ;) But even at realistic values, a resistor at 1mA will have a different resistance from one at 2mA because of self heating effects.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated a constant current source provides a steady current even if the resistance of the load varies, which is very valuable to circuit designers.

[image]

For example, in the above circuit the load could be a resistor or whatever. The current source supplies 50mA to it regardless of whether the load resistance varies. So in your problem 5A current goes through the 1k resistor and as the result the resistor drops 5,000V.